# What will happen if reply to Ping without payload?

Tags: networking, ping, icmp

I'm trying to figure out what is inside the payload of an ICMP packet for Ping. Wikepedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)#Payload) says it can be filled with data for different purposes. I only want to figure out if a server is reachable, so I simply ran a command:

```
ping $server
```

Wireshark showed the 48 byte payload being something with a "random" leading value and ending with "101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f". Repeating the command changed the leading value but the ending kept unchanged. The server always replied with the same payload.

So if I implement my own software and reply to this request with the correct identification and sequence number, but without including a payload in the server, will the client accept this as a valid response? If not, what could go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It will work, because default handler doesn't check payload when catch Echo-Reply. But ICMP-header must have same ID and SN.